# Trying to do some task with user highlighted text, how do I get what the user has highlighted?

Tags: javascript

Hello again stack overflow community. I want to have the user highlight some text on any webpage he or she is at. Then, I want to use a function DoSomething() on just the text that the user has highlighted. Is there any convenient way of doing this? I have been looking all over for information on this, but with no luck.

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263953/targeting-highlighted-text-in-javascript

Comment: Neat thank you for the link!